# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've already tried a lot of ways to solve this problem but I can't find an answer to this error:

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Here is my code:

```
def CalculaDeltaT(Tn, Tm, Fr, T, P):
    return (Tn * Fr * T) - (P * T) - (Tm * T)

deltaT = CalculaDeltaT

def CalculaDeltaR(Rn, Fv, Rm, Mt, R):
    return (Rn * Fv * R) - (Rm * Mt * R)

deltaR = CalculaDeltaR    

def CalculaDeltaV(Vn, Vm, Mr, V):
    return (Vn * V) - (Vm * Mr * V)

deltaV = CalculaDeltaV

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tmax = 10
Tp = [0] * tmax

Tn = 0.2
Fr = 0.6
Tm = 0.3
P = 0.1

T = [0] * tmax

T[0] = 10

Rn = 0.4
Fv = 0.6
Rm = 0.1
Mt = 0.2

R = [0] * tmax    
R[0] = 10

Vn = 0.5
Vm = 0.8
Mr = 0.8

V = [0] * tmax    
V[0] = 10

print(len(V))
print(len(R))
print(len(T))
print(len(Tp))

for i in range (1, tmax): 
    T[i] = T[i-1] + deltaT(Tn, Fr, Tm, T[i-1], P)
    Tp[i] = i

plt.plot(Tp, T)
plt.axis(0, 10, 10, 1000)
plt.ylabel('T[Tubarões]')
plt.xlabel('Tempo[em anos]')
plt.title(r'T em função de Tempo')
plt.show()
```

I've tried debugging but I couldn't find were the problem was. I am a student so I am sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: Include full error in question.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the function you are calling on the line that throws the error. Also consider looking at how that function is used in the pyplot [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html). You are doing something different from how the function is supposed to be used. Can you see it?

Comment: Note: you probably mean to assign the function's return value to a variable, like so `deltaT = CalculaDeltaT()`. Instead, you assign the function itself to `deltaT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/experiments.py", line 8, in <module>
    plt.axis(0, 10, 0, 100)
  File "/home/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1417, in axis
    v = ax.axis(*v, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1337, in axis
    if len(v) != 4:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

`axis(v)` documentation:

> ....
>   sets the min and max of the x and y axes, with
>       v = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
>
> ....if `len(*v)==0`, you can pass in *xmin*, *xmax*, *ymin*, *ymax*
>       as kwargs selectively to alter just those limits without changing
>       the others.

You should either use `plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])` or `plt.axis(xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10)`.

(i also adjusted `ymin` and `ymax` to something that would show your current data, since `y` gets smaller values than the limits you set)

Result:

[image]